# Cells Overflow Row Value

Tags: excel, vba, overflow

```
Sub InsertRow()
Call BlankColumns
'Call DeleteZeros
'normalizes the data extracted from QM QSRs
'If Columns included in QSR Change, THe column references will have to be adjusted
Dim lastcol As Integer 'Idenfies How many Questions are in Dataset
Dim r2a As Long 'Row to copy
Dim nr As Integer '# of people to copy
Dim r2s As Integer 'will copy each data set for however many questions there is
Dim R As Integer 'Counts how many people are in the dataset

R = Range("A4", Range("A4").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    With ActiveSheet
        lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 6
         r2a = (lastcol / 2) - 2
         r2s = (lastcol / 2)
             End With
    
For nr = 0 To R
     Cells(((nr * r2s) + 4), 1).EntireRow.Copy
    
         Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset((r2a), 0)).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Next nr

Call pasteanswers
Call PasteActivityCode

Question = MsgBox("Upload information to Database?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Database Upload")

If Question = vbYes Then
Call SaveWorkbook
Call ExportData

Else

End If


End Sub
```

The Error is occurring within

```
Cells(((nr * r2s) + 4), 1).EntireRow.Copy
```

[image]
With the code above I am having issues when  the cells row value is greater than  32,768, how do I make this allow for Long instead of Integer

I am not sure how to define this cell to allow it to reference rows greater than an integer. Alternative solutions are also appreciated!

Comment: What version of excel are you using?

Comment: Make sure all variables are Long by explicitly declaring them; `Dim R as Long` etc

Comment: I'm using excel 2013, i'll include the whole code to give a clearer picture and exactly where the overflow is occurring!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Dim nr As Integer '# of people to copy
> Dim r2s As Integer 'will copy each data set for however many questions there is
> Dim R As Integer 'Counts how many people are in the dataset
> ```

Change to:

```
Dim nr As Long
Dim r2s As Long
Dim R As Long
```

Whenever you deal with worksheet rows, or any value that doesn't fit the maximum value of a 16-bit integer (`Integer`), you need to declare your variables as `Long`, because 32,768 overflows an `Integer`, as you've noticed.

---

That said, I'd warmly recommend you rename these variables to use **meaningful identifiers**, so that you don't need a comment to tell you what they represent.

```
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim rowToCopy As Long
Dim nbPeopleToCopy As Long
Dim r2s As Long 'sorry, not clear from comment or usage
Dim nbRows As Long
```

Comment: Thank you! just realized that and was coming here to point out that I realized the variables themselves had to be converted to Longs, 
Thank you so much!

Comment: Correct. That's what *declaring a variable* does: it *allocates* a chunk of memory to hold that value - specifying a type determines how large that chunk needs to be: `Integer` is a signed 16-bit integer type; `Long` is a signed 32-bit integer type. If you're on 64-bit Office, then you also get a signed 64-bit integer type, `LongLong`. A variable that says "I need 16 bits of memory (2 bytes)", or one that says "I need 32 bits of memory (4 bytes)", reserves that much space in memory up front: it's less work than allocating a `Variant` on-the-fly and working out the type dynamically.